# Google Cloud - Copy Persistent Disk Snapshots To Another Project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snapshot

I have few disks which I daily make a snapshot of through the scheduled snapshot feature:
https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/snapshots?tab=schedules

I want to copy these snapshots to another project in order to prepare for a case of a disaster(for example project gets deleted).

How can i have a copy of these snapshots in a different project?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot copy a snapshot from one project to another. You can create a new disk from a snapshot in another account and then create a new snapshot.

Answer (score 3):

Few things to know:

- Snapshot are regional and can't be shared
- Image are global and can [be shared](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/managing-access-custom-images#share-images-within-organization). You can also [export the image to Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image#exporting_an_image_with_a_single_command)

So, create an [image based on your snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images#create_image)

```
gcloud compute images create image-name \
  --source-snapshot source-snapshot \
  --storage-location location
```

Then share it, or export it (according with the location that you want to keep your image)